# Cannot put INSERT STATEMENT inside TRIGGER body on SQL Fiddle

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I have a simple trigger, it runs on SQL Fiddle but it doesn't allow me to move my INSERT STATEMENT inside the trigger's body.
[my code on sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17cfe/1/1)
I simply want to move this line

```
INSERT INTO t2(start_date) VALUES (CURDATE());
```

inside the body of this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER UPDATE ON t1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  -- here, i want to put the simple INSERT STATEMENT here
END;
```

can't seem to get it to accept that on sqlFiddle

When I try it

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER UPDATE ON t1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t2(start_date) VALUES (CURDATE());
END;
```

it gives me this error:Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the delimiter to / (slash).

```
CREATE TABLE t1
    (
     id INT auto_increment primary key, 
     value INT(11) 
    )
/
CREATE TABLE t2
    (
     id INT auto_increment primary key,
     start_date DATE
    )
/


INSERT INTO t1( value ) VALUES( 100 )
/

CREATE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER UPDATE ON t1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO t2( start_date ) VALUES ( now() );
END;
/


UPDATE t1 SET value = 10
/
```

Demo --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aecc7/1